# uncountable noun a piece of clothing

Tags: nouns

Is there difference in usage of "a piece of clothing" and "an item of clothing"

Can I write or say "three items of clothing" and "three pieces of clothing"? Are they used similarly?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "pieces" is a more casual way to refer to "items". I wouldn't use "pieces" on a commercial website or on a sign in my store.

The only rare exception I can think of (which I've never seen in use) when these two might have different meanings is when two *pieces* of clothing or more are part of the same *item*.

Comment: +1 for bringing up examples like a 2-piece bathing suit. It can be regarded as one item (a swimsuit) with two pieces (a top and a bottom) – especially in the context of retail.